# User unable to verify account using Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, email, activation, createuserwizard

I have a simple create user wizard and custom membership provider which was taken from [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider)

Now I am following this tutorial by [scott Mitchell](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020153319/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/062508-1.aspx) and creating new user using wizard and able to send email by setting Disable create property user to "False" so that whenever user recieves the activation link he needs to click that and verifies his account.

Now the problem is when he creates new user it is working fine and when he tried to login immediately he gets message that he needs to ativate the link first in order to login.

And after registration he gets email and when he clicks the link it gives me error that there is no user in the database.

As you can see below that user gets activation link
[image]

When the user tried to click it he gets that he is not found in the database
[image]

And if i check in the administration tool If I check the user is available without a tick beside it.
[image]

Here is my web.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="HDIConnectionString"
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|HDIMembershipProvider.mdf"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="CustomProvider">
      <providers>
        <add connectionStringName="HDIConnectionString" name="CustomProvider"
          type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <membership defaultProvider="HDIMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="HDIMembershipProvider" type="HDI.AspNet.Membership.HDIMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="HDIConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <machineKey validationKey="C50B3C89CB21F4F1422FF158A5B42D0E8DB8CB5CDA1742572A487D9401E3400267682B202B746511891C1BAF47F8D25C07F6C39A104696DB51F17C529AD3CABE" decryptionKey="8A9BE8FD67AF6979E7D20198CFEA50DD3D3799C77AF2B72F" validation="SHA1"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" loginUrl="Login.aspx" />
    </authentication>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="adminEmail" value="noreply@xyz.com"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="xyz@gmail.com">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" password="password" port="587" userName="xyz@gmail.com"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

And code behind for createuser.aspx:

```
 Protected Sub CreateUserWizard1_SendingMail(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.MailMessageEventArgs) Handles CreateUserWizard1.SendingMail
        Dim userInfo As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(CreateUserWizard1.UserName)

        'Construct the verification URL
        Dim verifyUrl As String = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) & Page.ResolveUrl("~/Verify.aspx?ID=" & userInfo.ProviderUserKey.ToString())

        'Replace <%VerifyUrl%> placeholder with verifyUrl value
        e.Message.Body = e.Message.Body.Replace("<%VerifyUrl%>", verifyUrl)
    End Sub
```

Verify Page_Load:

```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'Make sure that a valid querystring value was passed through
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("ID")) OrElse Not Regex.IsMatch(Request.QueryString("ID"), "[0-9a-f]{8}\-([0-9a-f]{4}\-){3}[0-9a-f]{12}") Then
            InformationLabel.Text = "An invalid ID value was passed in through the querystring."
        Else
            'ID exists and is kosher, see if this user is already approved
            'Get the ID sent in the querystring
            Dim userId As Guid = New Guid(Request.QueryString("ID"))

            'Get information about the user
            Dim userInfo As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(userId)
            If userInfo Is Nothing Then
                'Could not find user!
                InformationLabel.Text = "The user account could not be found in the membership database."
            Else
                'User is valid, approve them
                userInfo.IsApproved = True
                Membership.UpdateUser(userInfo)

                'Display a message
                InformationLabel.Text = "Your account has been verified and you can now log into the site."
            End If
        End If
```

And here is the database screenshot:
[image]

Comment: What about the code in verify.aspx - can you post it please?

Comment: @Baldy-I have already updated it.Sorry for that:)

Comment: Is there a user in the database with the GUID from the URL-Parameter?

Comment: @Kiran: Does `Membership.GetUser(new GUID("7041053a-792f-47e0-bf2e-92febda23f09"))` always returns `null`, i mean from debugger in any context? Does it work for other (approved) GUIDs?

Comment: @Tim-It always returns null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tim and Baldy-I have finally got working but not with UserID.I don't know what's wrong with the GUID and I tried it with username and it's working perfectly.

So if any modifications with the GUID please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a guid type to the GetUser method of the Membership class.

**UPDATE**  Have tested this now.  Passing a GUID does call the correct overload - `GetUser(object providerUserKey)`.  So this answer is not relevant.

How can you be sure that this is being inferred to the correct overload at runtime?

[GetUser has both string and object single parameter overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152019.aspx), therefore it would make sense to pass the guid in as an object so you are explicitly stating which overload you want to call.

The framework may be calling ToString() on your guid, which would invoke the overload that looks up the username rather than the provider key.

Not at a computer right now, but it should go like this...

```
      Dim key as new object()
'put the guid in the object type
    key = Userid
    Dim user = Membership.GetUser(key)
```

Comment: @Baldy-So how do I change that can you please post some code for that?

Comment: @Baldy: He is calling the overload that takes an object, becaus he passes already a GUID. If it would be a string or a boolean, the other overloaded versions of GetUser would be called.

Comment: Have added an example for you

Comment: @Baldy: Apart from Kiran's code, yours would not work definitely. You are passing a string to GetUser. But that overload takes a UserName despite of a GUID.

Comment: I cant test it as im not at a pc.  However, he needs to be certain that the correct overload is being called.  Have updated code to pass guid into object instead.  He needs to try this to eliminate it from the list of potential causes. You say 'that overload' yet there are 2 single parameter overloads

Comment: @Baldy-It gives me an error as Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Guid'.

Comment: I updated the code, did you try passing the guid directly to the object?

Comment: @Baldy-I have tried with your updated code even though it shows me the same.